# cassandra node often turns down

Tags: cassandra, centos

i had 2 data centers , each contain one node

my cluster is like

previous cluster configuration

[image]

have alomost 15 keyspaces...but only three keyspaces contain data..and the data is only stored in one node which is present in DC1

So i changed the configuration as that two nodes present in same data center with different racks...for distributing the data between the two nodes...for that
i decommisioned the 31 node and re added that node to DC1

And i changed  all the keyspaces replication as

ALTER KEYSPACE input_data_profile WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1' : 1};

so now my cluster is like

present cluster configuration

[image]

and i ran nodetool repair on two nodes

but data is not distributed between nodes ....owns shows almost equal distribution but load shows that only 30 server contain data and 31 not contains...

30 server often turns down...to up the server it takes almost 30-40 min time..i thought that all the data present in single node is the reason.... i frustated alot with this issue...so please can anybody

help me to fix this bug....

Comment: also, welcome to stack overflow! if you have 2 questions, please post 2 questions. :] 

in regards to your node issues - please also provide the logs.

Answer (score 0):

its possible that the un-even distribution of the data has to do with the data itself. Depending on how you stored the data (== designed the tables), it might ALL be sent to the same node.

I suggest you read this - https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/the-most-important-thing-to-know-in-cassandra-data-modeling-the-primary-key

and especially the bit about the partition key, wich governs which data is stored on which node.